# No sound in Photobooth recorded videos

Tags: macos

I have no sound in my videos recorded in Photobooth. This happens on any user account, and the mic is working. I am using macOS 10.12.2 (16C67).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, for some reason "Boom 2" caused my microphone input to always be "Aggregate audio device", which worked on all applications I tried except Photobooth. Uninstalling "Boom 2" resolved the issue.

Comment: Yeah, it's a well-known system-screwer. Glad you got it :)